# How to get the width of the td dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html-table, scrollable-table

How can I get the td width and make it dynamically change once you added a long text to them... Because I'm planning to have a table-body scrollable.. and I don't want to use the `clone()` is there way to make it happen?..

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="table-cont">
<div class="table-header">
    <table>
        <caption>

        </caption>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Width 1</td>
                <td>Width 2</td>
                <td>Width 3</td>
                <td>Width 4</td>
                <td>Width 5</td>
                <td>Width 6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="table-body">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Width 1</td>
                <td>Width 2</td>
                <td>Width 3</td>
                <td>Width 4</td>
                <td>Width 5</td>
                <td>Width 6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

script:

```
var tableHeader = $('.table-header').children('table').outerWidth(true);
var tableWidth = $('.table-header table tr td').width();
alert(tableWidth);
$('table-body tr td').append(tableWidth);
```

css:

```
.table-header,
.table-body{
border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
display: inline-block;
}
table {
border-collapse: 0;
border-spacing: 0;
border: 0;
}
table thead th,
table tbody tr td{
border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
padding: 5px 8px;
font-weight: normal;
table-layout: fixed;
}
table thead th:last-child,table tbody tr td:last-child{
border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var tableHeader = $('.table-header').children('table').outerWidth(true);
var tableWidth = $('.table-header table tr td').width();
alert(tableWidth);
$('.table-body table tr td').each(function(){
   $(this).append(' '+tableWidth);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYpcs/)

**Updated** for making the `th` with the same `width` as of `td`.

```
$('.table-body table tr th').each(function(){
   $(this).append(' '+tableWidth);
});
```

Comment: is there a way also to make the th are the same with the width of the td so that when the td change with the th also change its width according to the size of the td.. ?

Comment: @JohnLouieBiñas test the above I've made changes in it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the width use:

```
$('table-body tr td').width(tableWidth);
```